# Tfs 2017 search internal server error

Tags: elasticsearch, tfs

We have: multi tier TFS 2017 update 3.

recently i moved  elasticsearch from one of application tiers to another server. 
So What did i do:

1. deleted elasticsearch service using cmd: sc delete servicename.
2. deleted IndexStore folder
3. deleted this tables

   [Search].[tbl_IndexingUnit]

   [Search].[tbl_IndexingUnitChangeEvent]

   [Search].[tbl_IndexingUnitChangeEventArchive]

   [Search].[tbl_JobYield]

   [Search].[tbl_TreeStore]

   [Search].[tbl_DisabledFiles]

   [Search].[tbl_ResourceLockTable]

   from all collection DB's
4. Installed elasticsearch at another server (actually it is oone of sql servers of our TFS instance)
5. Checked that service is  avaliable at url : http://SearchUrl:9200
6. Set up both AT's search feature at http://SearchUrl:9200
7. Tried To search something.

Result: 
1.Search returns "There was a problem processing your request.
Internal Server Error".

2. Index folder is only 36.5 Kbytes
3. In windows logs there is unhandled exception:

Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v4.0.30319
Service Host: 9025d248-2b1b-48a7-bb43-8abf779eeeaa (Development)
Process Details:
  Process Name: w3wp
  Process Id: 2580
  Thread Id: 4688
  Account name: Username

Detailed Message: TF30065: An unhandled exception occurred.

how can i fix it?

Comment: Did a member of Microsoft support instruct you to make modifications to your TFS operational store schema? If not, by doing so you have put your TFS installation into an unsupported state. Your best recourse in that case is to restore a backup of your TFS instance to **before** you made those changes. You should **never** directly modify anything in your team project collection databases, and especially not drop tables.

Comment: It appears there is guidance that instructs removing data from those tables. It does **not**, however, instruct you to drop them. Did you follow this guidance **exactly**, including running the indicated PowerShell scripts? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tapas_sahoos_blog/2017/09/11/resetting-search-index-in-team-foundation-server/

Comment: Today i will restore data from backups and try again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well. Now it works
What did i do:
1) Restored all deleted tables :)
2) Set up Elasticsearch on a separate server

3) Removed search feature from AT servers

4) Deleted all data from tables

```
[Search].[tbl_IndexingUnit]
[Search].[tbl_IndexingUnitChangeEvent]
[Search].[tbl_IndexingUnitChangeEventArchive]
[Search].[tbl_JobYield]
[Search].[tbl_TreeStore]
[Search].[tbl_DisabledFiles]
[Search].[tbl_ResourceLockTable]
```

5) removed all search extensions
6) instaled search feature. Configured it to the elastic server
7) waited for indexing

Actually, i've noticed that "unhalndled exception" in search disappeared after indexation finished

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message "`TF30065: An unhandled exception occurred.`" Seems it's similar with this issue : [Search Code and Work Items does not work after upgrade to 2017 Update 2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/81722/search-code-and-work-items-does-not-work-after-upg.html)

Add based on [David Jansen [MSFT]'s comments](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/97723/view.html), you can try calling the Re-index scripts manually to fix that. The solution is also mentioned in the link [Resetting Search Index in Team Foundation Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tapas_sahoos_blog/2017/09/11/resetting-search-index-in-team-foundation-server/) provided by Daniel's comment above.

> There is a dedicated "code search server". I used the latest Code
>   Search Tools scripts (TFS2017.2) and did a WipeAndRestart, followed by
>   manually calling the Re-index scripts. This did the trick.

More related information you can reference below articles:

- [Manage Search in Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/search/code/administration?view=vsts#manage-search-in-team-foundation-server)
- [Re-index a repository or collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/search/code/administration?view=vsts#re-index-a-repository-or-collection)

Comment: Ok. We've restored all tables from backup and now will try to do upwrote  instructions